# Is "not enough exhaustive" correct?

Tags: adjectives, questions, exam-questions

Two options to complete the following sentence:

> Is it _____ exhaustive or not _______ exhaustive?

Options:

> 1. too
> 2. too / too
> 3. enough

According to my teacher it's "Is it **too** exhaustive or not **enough** exhaustive?", and she says that in American English it's not commonly said like that, yet in British English it is.

Is she right?

Comment: Sorry, on a second read, I would say "not exhaustive enough;" was this a choice?   *Not enough exhaustive doesn't work.

Comment: It is too confused to be inflicted on ELL.

Comment: I find the whole idea of grading “exhaustive” misguided.  It’s either exhaustive or it’s not.  Maybe they mean exhausting?

Comment: @Jim in theory something is either exhaustive or not, in practice "too exhaustive" is fairly understandable as "trying too hard/taking up too many resources in order to be exhaustive".

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exhaustive), exhaustive means "complete and including everything". With that definition, it should not be [gradeable](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/adjectives-gradable-and-non-gradable): something can be complete or not complete, but it can't be very complete or too complete. What that means is that we should not be able to use adverbs of degree line **too** and **enough** with exhaustive.

Having said that, this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=too%20exhaustive&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoo%20exhaustive%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctoo%20exhaustive%3B%2Cc0) shows that we do often use **too exhaustive**. It is clear than in some of the examples I checked, the writer actually meant **too exhausted**, but there were also credible examples where the meaning was correct, for example this one:

> A respected appellate judge writes, “ My experience teaches ... that too few law review articles prove helpful in appellate decision making. They tend to be too talky, too unselective in separating the relevant from the irrelevant, too exhaustive." - *Legal reasoning and Legal writing, Richard K. Neumann 2005*

---

When we use **[enough](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enough)** as a determiner, it goes before a noun:

> Do you have **enough** money to pay the rent?

When we use an adverb to qualify an adjective, the adverb normally goes before the adjective. As the "Words and phrases that go before and after adjectives" section in [this article](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjective-phrases-position) explains, there is one notable exception- **enough**, which always follows the adjective it modifies. Here is an example:

> This tea isn't sweet **enough**.

When we use **[too](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/too)** to qualify an adjective, it follows the rules, and always goes before the adjective.

> This tea is **too** sweet.

In your sentence, the words are being used as adverbs to qualify an adjective, and the blank spaces are before adjectives. The third option (enough) does not work in either position, but the other two are OK. Reading the question again, it does state that two of the options are acceptable.

> 1. Is it **too** exhaustive or not exhaustive? -
> 2. Is it **too** exhaustive or not **too** exhaustive?